# Tinny audio after switching monitors

Tags: audio, display, hdmi

**Issue**

After switching monitors (AOC 27", built-in speakers -> LG Ultra gear 27GN600 ), i've been experiencing  very tinny and compressed audio through my logitech 3.1 setup.

**My Setup**

Since I run both my PS5 and PC through the monitor via HDMI ports, I just use the aux port on the monitor to supply sound to both setups. The setup was/is the same for both the old AOC and the new LG monitor.

**Notes**

The issue seems very much related to the new monitor. If i run the audio through either system (PS5 or PC) directly, the issue is resolved. If i run it through the aux port on the monitor, it sounds like utter garbage and is nearly impossible to suffer through. Looking for any suggestions here, as countless google searches have not provided me with the solution.

Comment: Are you sure you have it connected to the actual audio out 3.5mm jack and not the headphone jack?

Comment: Ah. It appears my monitor only has a 'headphone out' jack. I am guessing that my previous AOC monitor had an audio out jack. Well that sucks. @LawrenceC

Comment: I guess I'll just be silently filled with an unquenchable rage until I find a remedy to that. Thanks @LawrenceC

Comment: They make RCA red+white to 3.5mm adapters.  That might work if the monitor has the RCA red and white (L and R) jacks

Comment: The monitor only has HDMI x 2, Display port, and a headphone jack. @LawrenceC